# How to console log table id?

Tags: javascript

Just simple question, im very little bit in JS.

in the add table button, im adding and append new table into `.tab-content` div. (No need to show the button code) .

---

```
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.Index) {
        localStorage.Index = Number(localStorage.Index) + 1;
    } else {
        localStorage.Index = 1;
    }
} else {

}

function getTableList() {
    var addTable = '<div class="tab-pane" id="folder' + localStorage.Index + '">' +
        '<div class="zf-table">' +
        '<table id="table' + localStorage.Index + '" class="table table-bordered table-hover myFade">' +
        '<thead>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<th style="border-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);"></th>' +
        '<th>Audience Name</th>' +
        '<th>Type</th>' +
        '<th>Size</th>' +
        '<th>Date Created</th>' +
        '<th>Action</th>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</thead>' +
        '</table>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
    return addTable;
}

let newtableHTML = getTableList();
$('.tab-content').append(newtableHTML);
```

How to store table ID into console.log?

```
<table id="table' + localStorage.Index + '" class="table table-bordered table-hover myFade">
```

Log will be display

`table1`

`table2`

when user adding new table.

Comment: I would suggest making `Index` an argument to the function. That will make the code easier to test and allow it to work even if `typeof Storage !== "undefined"` were `false`. Right now, your code will just fail which makes the check pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a log statement in your getTableList function...

```
function getTableList() {
  console.log("table" + localStorage.Index);
  // rest of your function...
```

That way each time it is called the log with output the table id.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log('table' + localStorage.Index)`